# How do i make "facebook zoom"

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-manipulation, positioning, photo

Im making a website, and i love the functionality of this google chrome extension call Facebook Photo Zoom @ https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/elioihkkcdgakfbahdoddophfngopipi

I think the essential idea behind the extension is when you hover over the thumbnail, it grabs the original image file and displays it in full view. If the image is too big, then it will be position on the corners or the top and bottom bars of the window. If it is not too big, it will float next to the mouse position.

The logic behind it i understand, but the actually coding seems to be a bit daunting. I guess the only parts of it i dont understand is how do you code the positions of the expanded images and make them contract/expand when you move your mouse to the left/right. Thanks

Comment: Did u figure it out?? if yes please share the code

Comment: Sample problem here.  It could be some CSS trick rather than Javascript/Jquery but still I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

[13 zoom jquery plugins in here](http://www.designdim.com/2010/12/13-outstanding-jquery-image-zoom-effects/). Choose the best for your needs:)

Comment: The problem with this is that im not zooming into an image, when i hover over a thumbnail, i am getting the original large image, not the zoomed in version of the thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [preview image](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/) tooltip which is similar to what that Chrome extension does, but you have to provide it the url to the thumbnail and full sized image. Here is the original [blog post](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery).

---

I modified the script to adjust the image size to fit the distance between the cursor and right browser edge. It's not perfect, but it works. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bW9Gg/).

```
/*
 * Image preview script
 * powered by jQuery (http://www.jquery.com)
 *
 * written by Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
 *
 * for more info visit http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery
 *
 */

this.imagePreview = function(){
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 20;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $('a.preview').hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = '';
        var p, c = (this.t != '') ? '<br/>' + this.t : '';
        $('body').append('<p id="preview"><img src="' + this.href + '" alt="Image preview" />' + c + '</p>');

        // load image and get size
        p = $('#preview');
        p
            .fadeIn('fast')
            .find('img').load(function(){
                // get image dimensions after it has been loaded
                p.data('widths', [ $(window).width(), p.find('img').width() ]);
                // set image to 100% to fit in preview window
                $(this).width('100%');
                position(e);
            });
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;
        $('#preview').remove();
    });

    $('a.preview').mousemove(function(e){
        position(e);
    });

    var position = function(e){
        var w, prevw = $('#preview'),
            w = $.data( prevw[0], 'widths' );
        if ( w ) {
            prevw
                .css('top', e.pageY + yOffset)
                .css('left', e.pageX + xOffset)
                .css('max-width', (e.pageX + prevw.outerWidth() > w[0]) ?  w[0] - e.pageX - xOffset : w[1] || 'auto' );
        }
    };

};

// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

Comment: Its a good start, but it wont take into account when the image is off the window screen, so if  only half the image was shown, the javascript wont do anything about it

Comment: I've updated my answer, I don't think it works in IE6, but it should give you an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

on [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) you create big image with

```
css({position: 'absolute', left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY})
```

on [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) you update the left and top in the same way.

check also:

- http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/
- http://api.jquery.com/css/
- http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

Comment: But how does the image itself expand/contract depending on where the mouse position is. The code you wrote will move the image according to the mouse position, but how can the image dynamically resize base on the mouse position?

Answer (score 0):

See the Kabbar Image Zoomer at http://www.ideabonus.com/Kabbar/index.html